# Smart Table Client Side Pagination Not Working: Apex

Tags: angularjs, pagination, visualforce, apex, smart-table

I've followed the examples on Smart Table to a 'T'.  I'm unable to get Client Side pagination working.  The data is loading asynchronously, hence the `st-safe-src`.

The main issue is that the page length is not reducing to the defined length and none of the buttons are displaying.  There are zero errors in the console.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="RegulationOCheckController">

    <apex:stylesheet value="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <apex:includescript value="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js" />
    <apex:includescript value="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js" />
    <apex:includescript value="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.js" />
    <apex:includescript value="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-smart-table/2.1.8/smart-table.min.js" />

    <script>

        var app = angular.module('RegulationOCheck', ['smart-table', 'ui.bootstrap'])

        app.controller('CompareController', function($scope, DataService){

            DataService.regulationOCheck().then(function(data){

                $scope.collection = data

            })


        })

        app.factory('DataService', ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope){

            var funcs = {}

            funcs.regulationOCheck = function(){

                var deferred = $q.defer()

                RegulationOCheckController.compare(
                    '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}',
                    function(result, event){
                        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                            if(event.statusCode >= 200 || event.statusCode < 300){
                                deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(result))
                            }else{
                                deferred.reject(event)
                            }
                        })
                    },
                    { escape: false }
                )

                return deferred.promise

            }

            return funcs
        }])

    </script>

    <apex:pageBlock >

            <div ng-app="RegulationOCheck" ng-controller="CompareController">

                <table st-safe-src="collection" st-table="displayed" class="smart-table table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th st-sort="accountName">Insider Name</th>
                            <th st-sort="similarity ">% Similarity</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                <input st-search="accountName" placeholder="search for insider" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="row in displayed">
                            <td>{{ row.accountName }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.similarity }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center"
                                st-pagination=""
                                st-items-by-page="10"
                                st-displayed-pages="7"
                                colspan="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>

            </div>

    </apex:pageBlock>     

</apex:page>
```

Comment: create a plunker demo that reproduces problem

Comment: I am unable to repo the issue in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6nreETTabsF4USXupfrJ?p=preview).  I'm thinking this issue resides around the digest cycle.  I'm using JavaScript remoting to call an Apex service layer that returns data.

Comment: I think your problem is with `RegulationOCheckController`. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies inside the `DataService` factory, you get your data using a deferred constructor instead of utilizing a proper `$http` call.

You should replace this mess

```
funcs.regulationOCheck = function(){

            var deferred = $q.defer()

            RegulationOCheckController.compare(
                '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}',
                function(result, event){
                    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                        if(event.statusCode >= 200 || event.statusCode < 300){
                            deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(result))
                        }else{
                            deferred.reject(event)
                        }
                    })
                },
                { escape: false }
            )
            return deferred.promise
        }
```

With something along the lines of

```
funcs.regulationOCheck = function(){

            RegulationOCheckController.compare(
                '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}',
                function(result, event){
                    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                        if(event.statusCode >= 200 || event.statusCode < 300){
                            return $q.when(JSON.parse(result))
                        }else{
                            return $q.reject(event)
                        }
                    })
                },
                { escape: false }
            )
        }
```

or even `$http`

```
funcs.regulationOCheck = function() {
    return $http.get("data.json");
}
```

And avoid using `$rootScope.$apply`, it will call a digest cycle for all the application and it's totally not necessary for your scenario

Here is a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9RGxWFCGyYHJickd26KS?p=preview)

Comment: Due a Salesforce imposed Callout Depth limit I was forced to utilize JavaScript Remoting to call the Apex controller's compare method.  Unfortunately this "mess" is necesary.  I'm not sure how to get around the Callout Depth limit any other way.  I'd love to simply be able to use the $http module.

Comment: can you run the function inside `$rootScope.$apply` without the  `$rootScope.$apply` ?

Comment: Yes I can.  I removed the $rootScope.$apply() apply.  Also refactored my code as to steer away from the anti-pattern implementation.  Still receiving the same issue.  The data set is being returned from the web service correctly, but the smart table isn't rendering as expected.  I'm not sure how to dig deeper.